# Existing project built in VS on Windows to VS on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac

So I have a large web app (non-MVC) that I have built in Visual Studio running virtually on my Mac.

Was thinking of trying to switch to VS on Mac so that I can stop using my virtual windows, at last. But, will it really work? What I mean is, as far as I have read VS for Mac only supports .Net Core. Will that impact my current solution at all?

Is there anything else I need to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net core does not support web forms.   VS for the Mac does not support "Classic" asp.net The closest thing to web forms is razor pages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio